# How to change the default placement of the grid element when using maps control type in a native mobile app

Tags: genexus

When the user clicks on a grid element using the maps control type, the default behavior is that the row information is displayed almost over the map point. I want it to be displayed at the bottom of the panel. I believe it could be done with css but I wasnt able. I tried making changes to the class that defines the grid style.

Does any knows if its possible?